# Need help executing an XQuery from basex standalone

Tags: basex

I'm using Basex 8.0 beta on ubuntu 14.04

My database contains XML documents with elements that look like this

> ```
> <messages>
>   <message>      
>     <message-time-stamp>
>       <date>20141004</date>
>       <time>193843</time>
>       <utc-offset>-0400</utc-offset>
>     </message-time-stamp>
>   </message>
> </messages>
> ```

I can use the following xquery in the BaseX gui to update all message-time-stamp nodes with a concatenated timestamp

> ```
> declare variable $data := db:open('testdb');
>
>   (: Find all elements with time and return the parent element :)
>   for $n in $data//../time/..
>   return (
>     if (exists($n/utc-time-stamp)) then ()
>    else insert node 
>      <utc-time-stamp>
>      {fn:concat (
>         fn:substring($n/date, 1, 4),"-",
>         fn:substring($n/date, 5, 2),"-",
>         fn:substring($n/date, 7, 2),"T",
>         fn:substring($n/time, 1, 2),":",
>         fn:substring($n/time, 3, 2),":",
>         fn:substring($n/time, 5, 2),
>         fn:substring($n/utc-offset, 1, 3),
>         fn:substring($n/utc-offset, 4, 2))}
>      </utc-time-stamp> into $n
> )
> ```

I embedded the query in a basex script test_bxs.xqy as follows:

> ```
> <commands>
>   <xquery>
>   declare variable $data := db:open('testdb');
>   (: Find all elements with time and return the parent element :)
>   for $n in $data//../time/..
>   return (
>     if (exists($n/utc-time-stamp)) then ()
>     else insert node 
>      <utc-time-stamp>
>      {fn:concat (
>         fn:substring($n/date, 1, 4),"-",
>         fn:substring($n/date, 5, 2),"-",
>         fn:substring($n/date, 7, 2),"T",
>         fn:substring($n/time, 1, 2),":",
>         fn:substring($n/time, 3, 2),":",
>         fn:substring($n/time, 5, 2),
>         fn:substring($n/utc-offset, 1, 3),
>         fn:substring($n/utc-offset, 4, 2))}
>      </utc-time-stamp> into $n 
>   )
>   </xquery>
> </commands>
> ```

And execute as follows:

> ```
> $ basex -d -c test_bxs.xqy
> org.basex.query.QueryException: Syntax: <xquery>[query]</xquery>
>         at org.basex.core.parse.XMLParser.error(XMLParser.java:323)
>         at org.basex.core.parse.XMLParser.check(XMLParser.java:313)
>         at org.basex.core.parse.XMLParser.command(XMLParser.java:167)
>         at org.basex.core.parse.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:47)
>         at org.basex.core.parse.CmdParser.parse(CmdParser.java:57)
>         at org.basex.core.parse.CommandParser.parse(CommandParser.java:75)
>         at org.basex.core.parse.CommandParser.parse(CommandParser.java:54)
>         at org.basex.core.CLI.execute(CLI.java:88)
>         at org.basex.core.CLI.execute(CLI.java:77)
>         at org.basex.BaseX.<init>(BaseX.java:85)
>         at org.basex.BaseX.main(BaseX.java:42)
> org.basex.core.BaseXException: Syntax: <xquery>[query]</xquery>
>         at org.basex.core.CLI.execute(CLI.java:93)
>         at org.basex.core.CLI.execute(CLI.java:77)
>         at org.basex.BaseX.<init>(BaseX.java:85)
>         at org.basex.BaseX.main(BaseX.java:42)
> Caused by: org.basex.query.QueryException: Syntax: <xquery>[query]</xquery>
>         at org.basex.core.parse.XMLParser.error(XMLParser.java:323)
>         at org.basex.core.parse.XMLParser.check(XMLParser.java:313)
>         at org.basex.core.parse.XMLParser.command(XMLParser.java:167)
>         at org.basex.core.parse.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:47)
>         at org.basex.core.parse.CmdParser.parse(CmdParser.java:57)
>         at org.basex.core.parse.CommandParser.parse(CommandParser.java:75)
>         at org.basex.core.parse.CommandParser.parse(CommandParser.java:54)
>         at org.basex.core.CLI.execute(CLI.java:88)
>         ... 3 more
> Syntax: <xquery>[query]</xquery>
> ```

If I remove the insert statement and insert a db:output("."), the script runs fine from the command line, but of course does not update the database.

> ```
> <commands>
>   <xquery>
>   declare variable $data := db:open('testdb');
>   (: Find all elements with time and return the parent element :)
>   for $n in $data//../time/..
>   return (
>     if (exists($n/utc-time-stamp)) then (db:output("."))
>     else (db:output("."))
>   )
>   </xquery>
> </commands>
> ```

Since the script performs as expected in the GUI, I would expect similar results when using from the command line.

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BaseX command scripts should always have a file ending of `.bxs` as [outlined in the documentation](http://docs.basex.org/wiki/Commands#Basics).

The reason your approach fails is that in an XML command script you can not use XML elements, as the scripting language itself consists of XML elements. However, as it seems you only want to execute your xquery file, so simply store the XQuery itself (i.e. without surrounding commands and xquery elements) in a file and run it with

```
basex test_bxs.xqy
```

assuming your overwrite your existing file.

Comment: Actually the correct command would be $ basex test.xqy. Now that I read the document, it is clear. However, that doesn't explain why the script worked when I removed the 'insert' statement.

Comment: sure, sorry, that was merely a typo. I guess you not just remove the insert keyword, but the whole statement (i.e. including the concat and utc-timestamp). This way, no element would have been present in your query, which should work fine

Comment: For clarity then, how would a very simple insert be handled in my original attempt? (e.g. return insert node <test>xxxx</test> into $n )

Comment: well, I guess you wouldn't do it this way. Just store your xquery in a separate file (let's say file.xq) and in your command script (let's say cmd.bxs) you could run it with <run>file.xq</run>